# user registered, session working fine, not saving to database in openmeetings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openmeetings

I have installed openmeetings successfully. I have registered a user and logged in through this user. Session is running.

I have openmeetings database, users table. When i checked this, no datas are there. But issues are not there. Any idea what is going on

Comment: OpenMeetings by default uses the Apache Derby DB. Did you set up the db connection correctly ?

Comment: Yes it was saving in default Apache Derby DB. While installation i did not face any problem. I was using mysql DB. I followed this guide: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2013/03/14/installing-openmeeting-with-mysql. Please guide me, i want to save registered user to my database.

Answer (score 0):

renamed the "**db-persistence.xml**" for example **"mysql-persistance.xml**" file if you are using mysql "**persistance.xml**" and added mysql connector / j in the lib "webapps \ OpenMeetings \ WEB-INF \ lib "